# Не срабатывают события в jQuery

Tags: jquery, события

Здравствуйте!

Не срабатывает ни одно событие в jQuery. При этом в отладчике Google Chrome не возникает никаких ошибок, т.е. библиотека исправно подгружается. Помогите, пожалуйста.
В приведенном примере только .click() и .hover(), но, например, с .change() для инпутов и селектов такая же ерунда. Приходится вешать onchange="" на инпут/селект, очень неудобно.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#test").click( function () {
  alert('1');
})

$("#test").hover(
  function () {
    alert('1');
  },
  function () {
   alert('2');
  }
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="test">123</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно обернуть в

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

то есть так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click( function () {
      alert('1');
    })

    $("#test").hover(
      function () {
        alert('1');
      },
      function () {
       alert('2');
      }
    );
});
```

Обернутый код начинает работать лишь после загрузки, а иначе, если не все элементы загружены. то могут быть обращения к еще несуществующим элементам и как следствие ошибки и непонятки.

Comment: либо использовать вместе с "on" как вариант